# What is the equivalent of java's String.format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

I'm not looking for simple template literals, more so the functionalities of String.format from java.

For example,

```
String.format("%05d",num);
```

if inputted 14, would output 00014. How could I do this in javascript?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you're looking for? How does `%05d` turn into `00014` in Java?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Go read up on `String.format`. It's a lot like C's `printf`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this means that we want to pad left the number with zeros so that the number takes 5 characters. Here the number 14 is taking 2 characters, using `%05d` means we want to add three zeros to the left so that the result is five digits (00014).

Comment: `String(num).padStart(5, '0')`

Comment: Are you just looking for zero-padding, or do you want more functionality than that?

Comment: If all you need is padding left, you can check out [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: the duplicate answered my question, thanks